# Nicer solution for how to combine cells between two values in a second column

Tags: excel, merge, formula

Even though I came up with a solution for my problem, I was hoping someone might help find me a new one that is not so "cumbersome"

Here is my situation:

- a cell in column A either contains a value (time stamp) or is blank
- the number of blank cells between each time stamp varies
- a cell in column B always contains a value (string)

Here is what I need:

- in column C, combine the strings in column B between time stamps in column A

Since I know that the maximum number of blanks in Column A between two time stamps is 5, I created this function..(I deleted the space between "" and inserted a line break in front of every IF for display reasons)

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A2="",A3="",A4="",A5=""),B1&""&B2&""&B3&""&B4&""&B5,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A2="",A3="",A4=""),B1&""&B2&""&B3&""&B4,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A2="",A3=""),B1&""&B2&""&B3,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A2=""),B1&""&B2,
IF(ISNUMBER(A1),B1,"")))))
```

If the maximum number of blanks would be 10, the formula would get extremely long...so any ideas how to come to the same solutions in a more elegant way are appreciated!
Thanks,
Ivana

Comment: If you have Excel 2016, you can use `CONCAT` function.  You could use VBA.  You could use a formula that starts in C2 and concatenates B2 with the line above.

Comment: Much easier to do in VBA. Ron's method works but it will leave you with a building block of strings in the cell of column C in the same rows as the blanks in column A.  You would also need to ad an IF statement to check to see when the is a time stamp in column and and to start the concatenation over again from scratch.  something like:`if(A2<>"" then B1,B1&" "&C2)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Gotta be clear on the fact that [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) and [CONCAT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) are only available in [Excel 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73) with an Office 365 subscription (or Excel Online).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I should have specified that I use Excel 2013, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to add some columns, you could simplify your formula.

I would add three new columns instead of just one. My solution assumes that you have a header at the top in row 1.  It also allows for more than five blanks between timestamps, if that ever arises.

In row 2, enter the following formulas:

```
Column C: =IF(ISNUMBER(A2),B2,C1 & " " & B2)
Column D: =IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,D1)
Column E: =IF(D2<>D3,C2,"")
```

Paste or drag these down to the end of your timestamps and strings to fill in the columns.

Columns D and E will contain your timestamp and concatenated B string(s).  You can either pick them off or filter them to get the non-blank strings.

---

**EDIT FOR DUPLICATE TIMESTAMPS**

If duplicates can occur and you need to track them separately, then change column E in row 2 as follows:

```
Column E: =IF(ISNUMBER(A3),C2,IF(ISBLANK(B3),C2,""))
```

Copy down as before.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I was looking for. I even though about combining more functions in additional columns I just wasn't sure how to combine them correctly. As long as the time stamps are not identical (that should'n happen too frequently) it works perfectly!

Comment: If duplicate timestamps are possible, they should be accounted for.  Please see my revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some old [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) range addressing together with the newer [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)¹.

[image: xlol_text_join_timestamp]

In C2 as,

```
 =IF(A2<>TEXT(,), IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(44), TRUE, B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, A$1:A1))), TEXT(,)), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down as necessary.

---

¹ <sub>[TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) became available with [Excel 2016 with Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73) and Excel Online.</sub>

Comment: thanks for this great suggestion - I can see that you've put a lot work into it, I really appreciate it. I will seriously consider an upgrade to Excel 2016 (I am currently using the 2013 version) - I just have one small followup question: how can I alter the function if I want the Textjoin to combine the strings between the time stamps? In your example it would be the lines 2-7, 8-11, 12-14...